# Java - XML Parser & Downloader

Tags: java

I am creating a application that will download a lot of files from my own web server. But idk why it is not working. It dont have any response..

Here is some part of my code

Downloader.class

```
private Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY;
    public void downloadLibrary()
        {
            System.out.println("Start downloading libraries from server...");
            try
            {
                URL resourceUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/libraries.xml");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(resourceUrl.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream());
                NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Contents");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++)
                {
                    Node node = nodeLst.item(i);

                    if (node.getNodeType() == 1)
                    {
                        Element element = (Element)node;
                        String key = element.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                        File f = new File(launcher.getWorkingDirectory(), key);
                        downloadFile("http://www.example.com/" + key, f, "libraries");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error was found when trying to download libraries file " + e);
            }

        }

        public void downloadFile(final String url, final File path, final String fileName)
        {
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()
            {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
                {
                    launcher.println("Downloading file " + fileName + "...");
                    try
                    {
                        URL fileURL = new URL(url);
                        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(fileURL.openStream());
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Cannot download file : " + fileName + " " + e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                public void done()
                {
                    System.out.println(fileName + " had downloaded sucessfully");

                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
```

Here is some part of my xml file(libraries.xml)

```
<Key>libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.0/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar</Key>
```

My idea is, my application will read the XML file. Then it will download file from the server and save to computer. For example, my application download `http://www.example.com/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.0/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar` then it will save to `C://WorkingDir/libraries/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.0/lwjgl-2.9.0.jar`
There is ton of `<Key></Key>` in my XML file and i have to download all of it.

Is that any code wrong? Thanks for helping.

Comment: ahhhh! you've got C in your Java!!!!!

Comment: @SnakeDoc what did you mean?

Comment: Lol, joking of course. In java, most of the time you see the curly brace { on the same line, not the next line. usually when you see on the next line, it's either a student (since academics follow the next-line pattern usually) or someone with a C family language background. Not always, but just my observation. ;)

Comment: @SnakeDoc lololol, i through you said i am writing a C code.. Yea i prefers to put "{" in the next line but not the same line. This is my coding style :P

Comment: `fos.close()` missing. Better doe everything step wise first.

Comment: is your proxy messing with your connection?

Comment: @JoopEggen haha i forgot to put it, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @SnakeDoc i don't know what is proxy so i just simply put 'private Proxy proxy = Proxy.NO_PROXY;'

Comment: @user2718549 shouldn't matter then, didn't notice it was `NO_PROXY` constant. I usually just leave that out entirely (`openConnection()` is an overloaded method).

Comment: @SnakeDoc what do you mean by (openConnection() is an overloaded method)?

Comment: @user2718549 I mean there's more than one way to use it (as in what arguments it takes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try consuming the connection directly through a reader of some sort to a String first, then you can manipulate that however you need.

```
package come.somecompany.somepackage.utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class WebUtils {

    /**
     * Gets the HTML value of a website and
     * returns as a string value.
     * 
     * @param website website url to get.
     * @param ssl True if website is SSL.
     * @param useragent Specified User-Agent (empty string "" means use system default).
     * @return String value of website.
     */
    public String getHTML(String website, boolean ssl, String useragent) {
        String html = "";
        String temp;
        String prefix;
        if (ssl) {
            prefix = "https://";
        } else {
            prefix = "http://";
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL(prefix + website);
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        if (!(useragent.equalsIgnoreCase(""))) {
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", useragent);
        }
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            html += temp + "\n";
        }
        in.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return html;
    }
}
```

Also, it sort of looks like you are attempting to parse HTML using an XML pattern... which may give you difficulties. You could try out JSoup - it's a java HTML parser, and works pretty well and is easy: http://jsoup.org/

It may help with consuming documents from your website without needing to build your own downloader too.

`UPDATE --`

Try reading into a `BufferedReader`, perhaps your program isn't receiving the full document, buffered reader may help.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

So with your first method, something like:

```
public void downloadLibrary()
    {
        System.out.println("Start downloading libraries from server...");
        try
        {
            URL resourceUrl = new URL("http://www.example.com/libraries.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // change here
            URLConnection con = resourceUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String tempDoc = "";
            String tempStr;
            while (tempStr = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
                tempDoc += tempStr + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            }

            Document doc = db.parse(tempDoc);

            NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Contents");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = nodeLst.item(i);

                if (node.getNodeType() == 1)
                {
                    Element element = (Element)node;
                    String key = element.getElementsByTagName("Key").item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    File f = new File(launcher.getWorkingDirectory(), key);
                    downloadFile("http://www.example.com/" + key, f, "libraries");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error was found when trying to download libraries file " + e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: is it actual XML, or HTML that you are parsing as XML? Either way, using DOM for xml parsing is the long way (very verbose and a lot of boiler plate code, plus for large XML documents, it's not very efficient since it must store the entire document in memory during parsing). Personally I made the switch to JAXB recently and love it, but it's also a lot to setup. SAX parser imho is the easiest to setup once you learn it, and it's super fast.  --  this has nothing to do with your connection problem, but thought i'd just throw that out there ;-P

Comment: it is a actual XML. And my XML is not very large, it is only about 500KB. I prefer to use DOM cuz DOM is easy

Comment: 1 mistake... while (tempStr = bfr.readLine()) != null) Error :  cannot convert from String to boolean

Comment: whoops, needed extra set of () -- so like: `while ((tempStr = brf.readLine()) != null) { // concat to string }`

Comment: @user2718549 that would mean it's not being passed the `http://` or 'https://' etc... make sure you are using `java.net.URL` and not anything else (like from `java.io.*` or something).

Comment: i am so sorry cuz i found that there is something wrong in my XML file...I accept your answer cuz your code also help me a lot. I am so sorry